# I need some troubleshooting with my HTML/JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create code that when you press a button, it will change the value of a variable and replace some text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="unitts">You have 0 unitts</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var unitt = 0;
        function unittIncrease() {
            var unittPrev = unitt;
            unitt++;
            document.getElementById(unitts).innerHTML.replace("You have " +  unittPrev.toString() + " unitts.", "You have " + unitt.toString() + " unitts.");
        }
    </script>
    <button id="unittIncrease" onclick="unittIncrease();">Digitize Unitt</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I press the button, nothing happens to the text.
I don't know why this does not work.
Please help me!

**EDIT**: I am only 11 years old,
please don't throw your wizard
code at me.

> maybe you should remove your button system and add a while loop that
>   automatically add a unit but waits one second with a setInterval
>   function

Comment: You're using the same name for the event handler function and for your button. Change the name of one or the other.

Comment: Is it required of you to use `replace()`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say with that update? Do you mean none of the posted answers help? Where does that quoted paragraph come from?

Comment: @Vohuman It was just an example just in case. I used a quote because I didn't want people to ignore it. I know it's not the correct way to use it, but hopefully you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript should be (note the `unitts` wrapped in quotes and the full stop removed):

```
 document.getElementById('unitts').innerHTML = "You have " + unitt + " unitts";
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById(unitts).innerHTML.replace("You have " +  unittPrev.toString() + " unitts.", "You have " + unitt.toString() + " unitts.");
```

In the latter, it is looking for the non-existent variable `unitts` instead of the string `'unitts'`. Also, you are looking for the text `You have x unitts.` which cannot be found because in your HTML, it is just `You have x unitts` without the full stop.

---

**Edit**

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LmlpUa?p=preview).

Comment: It should be noted that the current snippet tries to replace the contents and doesn't do anything with the returned value.

Comment: Yeah, actually OP can just assign a value to `innerHTML` rather than doing a `replace()` operation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write the js code like this

```
document.getElementById('unitts').innerHTML = "You have"....
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById(unitts).innerHTML.replace("...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the issues that the other answer mentions, by calling `.replace` method on the `.innerHTML` property of the element, the content of it doesn't change. You should reset the property by using the returned value of the method call:

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(...);
```

Also, as you are trying to increase a number, instead of replacing all the characters, you can just replace the numeric part:

```
var unitts = document.getElementById('unitts');

function unittIncrease() {
    unitts.textContent = unitts.textContent.replace(/\d+/, function(n) { 
        return +n + 1;
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6odbosg/

Comment: Upvote for explaining `replace()` vs `innerHTML` and an alternative way of using `replace()`.